# "cannot find -lucontext" when installing some rubygems on newly pushed docker image ruby:2.7.4-alpine3.13

Tags: ruby, linux, docker, alpine-linux

I can no longer install the Rubygems `byebug` and `racc` on the `ruby:2.7.4-alpine3.13` image that was pushed in the last day. It seems something has been removed or moved.

To reproduce:

```
docker pull ruby:2.7.4-alpine3.13
2.7.4-alpine3.13: Pulling from library/ruby
Digest: sha256:89b589e1b6b334ed7af93da3d4c75dca5beef8f1a844594c3a865bc6c4f5b96e
Status: Image is up to date for ruby:2.7.4-alpine3.13

docker run --rm -it --entrypoint /bin/sh ruby@sha256:89b589e1b6b334ed7af93da3d4c75dca5beef8f1a844594c3a865bc6c4f5b96e
apk --no-cache add "build-base>=0.5"
gem install byebug
```

gives me:

```
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.
```

Following the logs down, I get:

```
current directory: /usr/local/bundle/gems/byebug-11.1.3/ext/byebug
/usr/local/bin/ruby -I /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0 -r ./siteconf20211027-12-7c6k46.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: /usr/local/bundle/gems/byebug-11.1.3/ext/byebug
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /usr/local/bundle/gems/byebug-11.1.3/ext/byebug
make "DESTDIR="
compiling breakpoint.c
compiling byebug.c
compiling context.c
compiling locker.c
compiling threads.c
linking shared-object byebug/byebug.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.2.1/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lucontext
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:262: byebug.so] Error 1
```

Looking for the header files we get:

```
find . -name ucontext.h
./usr/include/asm/ucontext.h
./usr/include/asm-generic/ucontext.h
./usr/include/sys/ucontext.h
./usr/include/ucontext.h
```

Installation of the byebug gem works using the digest to define the image that `ruby:2.7.4-alpine3.13` used to be on 19 October 2021 (`ruby@sha256:ace3785b1a5eb95d08285f8741e3dc1c481c479a271d54e37b8e45a7106d86c6`) but the image was updated in the last day, and something has changed in it.

When I run `find . -name ucontext.h` on the working image, the files are in the same location.

Anyone have any thoughts on how to get this working?

Comment: Seeing the same problem and error messages for our builds against racc and sassc. Locking the image SHA to the one in the description has solved it in the short term for us. Following this post!

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue. Seems like it was caused by this [commit](https://github.com/docker-library/ruby/commit/53a12c266a4bd3c1e5ade9907336cf52f694cc6b#diff-965e0beb30903644acdebd18fcddf8e305ae8b5b3638552dd82b3071117ec2af) I manually added the `libucontext-dev` Alpine package and included the command `export LIBS='-lucontext'` to my Dockerfile and my build started working again.

Comment: Thanks! Adding `RUN apk add "libucontext-dev>=1.0-r0"` to the Dockerfile fixed the problem for me, without the environment variable. Much appreciated.